# How often should we post articles?

Tags: discussion, blog

As of now, the blog has seen extremely random activity with the articles. I posted three in a day, skipped two, then posted two more followed by another one. This schedule is very random and will cause our readers to not quite know when the next article will come out.

So how often should we post articles on the blog? If you can, try adding the *type* of article that is posted if possible at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest once, maybe twice a week for starters.

The blog is not the main focus of this site. It is intended to *complement* this site, and if we commit too much of our time and effort to the blog, this site will suffer.

We should remain committed to posting quality content on this site, allowing the blog to be an outlet for content unsuitable for this site - tips, opinions, rants, updates, etc.

Let's start small and move up, rather than overwork ourselves and feel like we let everybody down.